# Could you help explain what @ does in Python

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

I have tried a number of different tutorials in python and regularly come across the @ symbol being used, but I am still not 100% sure what is going on.

This document describes how properties are used:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

```
@property
@temperature.setter
```

This document shows blueprints with flask
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/views/

```
@bp.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
```

This is used in pytest:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html

```
@pytest.fixture
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("cleandir", "anotherfixture")
```

This discussion mentions another type
[How do I correctly setup and teardown my pytest class with tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405380/how-do-i-correctly-setup-and-teardown-my-pytest-class-with-tests)

```
@classmethod
```

If you could offer any help, especially a good tutorial, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python

Comment: Those are called decorators, basically it's a way to add functionality to a function without altering it's code