# Pytest, using fixtures as instances of class in prolog method setup_method

Tags: python, design-patterns, pytest

I've started using unitest infrastructure that based on pytest for adding additional test class (see below `TestMyStuff`)

It seems that if I add the fixtures `xi` and `yi` as inputs of method `setup_method` it refer to them as functions from `fixtures.py`, but adding them to each of the test functions, they get their return value of `classX` and `classY` respectively rather then the function value.

Both test methods share identical code block which require `xi` and `yi`, and also an additional per-test unique code. 
I wish to take the common code and add it to `test_method` but for that I need that `xi` and `yi` as instances of `classX` and `classY` which the fixtures method returns, and not the methods themselves from `fixtures.py`

In brief, is there any way to share some pre-built fixtures between all class functions (both the test methods and the prolog method) ?

```
test_xy.py

from fixtures import *

class TestMyStuff
    def setup_method(self, test_method, xi, yi):
        # here xi and yi are functions :-(
        self.x = classX.makeX()
        self.y = classY.makeY()


    def test_X(self, xi, yi):
        # here xi and yi are instances of classX and classY
        # do shared stuff with xi and yi
        # do unique stuff with xi and yi

    def test_Y(self, xi,yi):
        # here xi and yi are instances of classX and classY
        # do shared stuff with xi and yi
        # do other stuff with xi and yi

fixtures.py

from classY import classY
from classX import classX


@pytest.fixture()
def xi(request):
    ...
    return classX(request.var1, request.var2, request.var3)
    #classX is implemented on different file called classX.py

@pytest.fixture()
def yi(request, xi)
    ...
    return classY(request.var1, xi)
```

Comment: Are you bound to the xUnit's `setup_method`? You can replace it with an autouse fixture that does effectively the same. Check out [my recent answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823587/2650249) for a code example.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you reply. I've read your answer, and the internal fixtures are called for each test which is great, but what if I want the internal fixtures to  operate just once for multiple test running. for example, if I run all tests in class `c:\Python27\Scripts\pytest.exe -k TestMyStuff`.

Comment: Just change the fixture scope to `class` so it executes once per class; I have an example for that in the answer. Search for text _One-time setup/teardown per class_.

Comment: If you mean the fixtures `xi`/`yi`, you can e.g. even adjust their scope to `session` and they will execute once for the whole test run; values will be calculated once when first requested and cached for subsequent requests.

Comment: But if I use `xi` and `yi` with scope `session` from the internal fixtures from scope `class` I get : `You tried to access the 'class' scoped fixture 'xi' with a 'session' scoped request object, involved factories`

Comment: Can you update your question with a failing example? I can't reproduce it locally.

Comment: It actually works now. I hadn't switched all my fixtures to the correct scope and therefore it failed before. But one more thing, can I control the scope using some sort of input parameters, since some other test classes are using the default scope for `xi` and `yi`. thanks !

Comment: You can't control the scope, and in fact you shouldn't. For example, a session scoped fixture changing the scope to class would suddenly redefine its return value, breaking the tests that expect it to be session-scoped. Scope sets are inclusive though, so test classes can use session-scoped fixtures very well. If you describe your problem, I'm sure there's a solution for it using fixtures only.

Answer (score 0):

From the pytest documentation:

`You can mix both fixture mechanisms in the same file but test methods of unittest.TestCase subclasses cannot receive fixture arguments.`

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html

I do not think you can build things as elegantly as you would like.