# Should I use a fixture to execute a setup function?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to move my `unittest` tests into `pytest` so I can easily parameterise them. The `setUp` function for one of the classes is:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.engine.execute(f'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {db1}')
    self.engine.execute(f'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {db2}')
```

What is the best way to replicate this in `pytest`? I realise there is `setup_method()` however I was cheating a little with `unittest` as not every method in that class needed that particular setup.

`pytest` [recommend](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/xunit_setup.html#:%7E:text=Method%20and%20function%20level%20setup%2Fteardown&text=setup_method%20is%20invoked%20for%20every,the%20method%20parameter%20is%20optional.) using fixtures but all the examples I see are returning objects, not executing functions. Can/should fixtures be used in this way?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to return anything from the fixture. Usually setup/teardown is done in a fixture with the part before `yield` executed before the test (setup), and the part after the `yield` after the test (teardown).

Comment: Your first comment answered my question :-) Happy to accept that as an answer?

Comment: Well, as this already has been answered before, it is better to flag this as a duplicate instead of repeating that answer - but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ah well I see my question as being different. I'd read through all the docs on fixtures so understood the logic of using them to setup and teardown objects. I just wasn't sure on using them to solely execute functions!

Comment: Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39401087/12480730) is exactly what I tried to describe.