# How to make sure the fixture executes after all tests have executed?

Tags: python, directory, pytest, fixtures

I have created several tests which create different files and folders in the test folder. I want to delete all the folders that have been created through the tests, but only at the end of the test execution. I have written this fixture:

```
import shutil

@fixture(scope='session',autouse=True)
def delete_files():
    yield None
    shutil.rmtree('test-folder')
```

But somehow this does not execute last, after all the tests have passed. How to solve this and to delete all the test folders at the end of test execution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly setup and teardown for my pytest class with tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405380/how-do-i-correctly-setup-and-teardown-for-my-pytest-class-with-tests)

Answer (score 2):

For another approach, I have made use of the `tmp_path` directory before, see [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/c3e3bb77e507f1997c1eb66f81265da4da12b68b/tests/test_persistence.py#L57-L65) for an example use case and [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html?highlight=tmp_path#pytest.tmpdir.tmp_path) for the docs of that fixture.