# Creating a test case for add user functionality for movie app

Tags: python, sqlite, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I'm trying to write a test case for the movie site that I'm creating. I want to test the `add_user` method. Each time I call `add_user()` from my test method, it is created a user in my SQLite db and then returns as a fail that the user already exist.

```
def add_user(self, name):
    param = {'name': name}
    query = text('Insert into users (name) values (:name)')
    check_usr_query = text('Select name from users '
                           'Where name = :name')

    check_usr = self._execute_query(check_usr_query, param).fetchone()

    if check_usr is not None:
       return 'User Already Exists in Database'
    else:
        with self.engine.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute(query, param)
            conn.commit()
        return 'Successfully added user'
```

```
import pytest
from DataManager.sql_data_manager import SQLiteDataManager

dataManager = SQLiteDataManager('DataManager/movie.db')

def test_add_user():
    name = 'Esth'
    test_data = dataManager.add_user(name)
    check_usr = dataManager.get_user_by_name(name)
    if test_data == 'Successfully added user':
        assert test_data == 'Successfully added user'
        print(name + ' added to db')
    elif test_data == 'User Already Exists in Database':
        assert check_usr is not None
        print(name + ' Already exists in the db')
```

Comment: you can add a setup step that removes it if it exists ... and a teardown step that removes it ... or you could create a new database for your tests...

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here:

1. Use [pytest teardown fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405380/how-do-i-correctly-setup-and-teardown-for-my-pytest-class-with-tests) to cleanup user on test complete
2. Remove user `Esth` on test launch if it exists
3. Create user with the [random name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits)
4. Create new database on every test run